# What are the practical differences between Fit, NonlinearModelFit, and FindFit

Tags: fitting

What are the practical differences between:
`FindFit`,`NonlinearModelFit`,and `Fit`. Do they call different fitting algorithms and routines? How can one tell which is best to use in a certain situation. How is it best to use them once you've chosen?

Comment: `Fit` does not contain without support for diagnostic of the defined model.
`NonlinearModelFit` contain, for instance, results of ANOVA, confidence intervals for parameters of model, information criteria as a BIC, AIC ....

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Fit` is limited to using a series of basis functions. It finds the parameters multiplied by the basis functions that fits the data in a least squares sense.

`FindFit`is capable of using very general functions that don't work with the `Fit` model. It will also find parameters that fits the data in a least squares sense.

`LinearModelFit` is the same as `Fit` with the additional ability of outputting a great deal of diagnostic information. The output can conveniently be used directly as a function.

Similarly `NonlinearModelFit` is the same as `FindFit` with the ability of outputting diagnostic information. The output can be used directly as a function.

Example:

```
data = Table[Prime[x], {x, 20}]
(* {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, \
59, 61, 67, 71} *)
```

### Fit

```
Fit[data, {1, x, x^2}, x]
(* -1.92368 + 2.2055 x + 0.0746753 x^2 *)
```

Plotting the result requires either copy and pasting the function or using `Evaluate` within `Plot`.

```
Show[
 Plot[Evaluate[Fit[data, {1, x, x^2}, x]],  {x, 1, 20}],
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### LinearModelFit

```
lm = LinearModelFit[data, {1, x, x^2}, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
lm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {-1.92368, 2.2055, 0.0746753} *)
```

Some diagnostic information

```
lm["CorrelationMatrix"]
(* {{1., -0.888805, 0.781116}, {-0.888805, 
  1., -0.971348}, {0.781116, -0.971348, 1.}} *)
```

Easier to plot. Can use `lm` directly as a function.

```
Show[
 Plot[lm[x],  {x, 1, 20}],
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### FindFit

Can use general functions.

```
FindFit[data, a x Log[b + c x], {a, b, c}, x]
(* {a -> 1.42076, b -> 1.65558, c -> 0.534645} *)
```

Same problem with plotting.

```
Show[
 Plot[Evaluate[
   a x Log[b + c x] /. 
    FindFit[data, a x Log[b + c x], {a, b, c}, x]],  {x, 1, 20}],
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### NonlinearModelFit

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a x Log[b + c x], {a, b, c}, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 1.42076, b -> 1.65558, c -> 0.534645} *)
```

Some diagnostic information

```
nlm["CorrelationMatrix"]
(* {{1., 0.844101, -0.998155}, {0.844101, 
  1., -0.872743}, {-0.998155, -0.872743, 1.}} *)
```

As with `LinearModelFit` can use the output directly as a function.

```
Show[
 Plot[nlm[x],  {x, 1, 20}],
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Beautifully detailed and explained answer. Thank you!

Comment: I agree that NonlinearModelFit is far more convenient than FindFit, because the former actually outputs a functional form, while the latter only outputs parameters that must then be substituted back into the model.  However, this distinction *does not* exist between LinearModelFit and Fit, since, they *both* output functional forms that can be used directly for plotting:   `lm = LinearModelFit[data, {1, x, x^2}, x];` `Show[Plot[lm[x], {x, 1, 20}], ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]` AND: `fit = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2}, x];` `Show[Plot[fit, {x, 1, 20}], ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]`